# Filling in gaps with awk or anything

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list such as below, where the 1 column is position and the other columns aren't important for this question.

```
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
5  1 2 3 4 5
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to fill in the gaps such that the list is continuous and it reads

```
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
3  0 0 0 0 0
4  0 0 0 0 0 
5  1 2 3 4 5
6  0 0 0 0 0 
7  0 0 0 0 0 
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am familiar with awk and shell scripts, but whatever way it can be done is fine with me.
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Which way did you try, awk or shell script? Where's your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this one-liner may work for you:

```
awk '$1>++p{for(;p<$1;p++)print p"  0 0 0 0 0"}1' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo '1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
5  1 2 3 4 5
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5'|awk '$1>++p{for(;p<$1;p++)print p"  0 0 0 0 0"}1'         
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
3  0 0 0 0 0
4  0 0 0 0 0
5  1 2 3 4 5
6  0 0 0 0 0
7  0 0 0 0 0
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following awk one-liner:

```
awk '{b=a;a=$1;while(a>(b++)+1){print(b+1)," 0 0 0 0 0"}}1' input.file
```

Tested with here-doc input:

```
awk '{b=a;a=$1;while(a>(b++)+1){print(b+1)," 0 0 0 0 0"}}1' <<EOF
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
5  1 2 3 4 5
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
EOF
```

the output is as follows:

```
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
3  0 0 0 0 0
4  0 0 0 0 0
5  1 2 3 4 5
6  0 0 0 0 0
7  0 0 0 0 0
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

Explanation:

On every input line `b` is set to `a` where `a` is the value of the first column. Because of the order in which `b` and `a` are initialized, `b` can be used in a `while` loop that runs as long as `b < a-1` and inserts the missing lines, filled up with zeros. The `1` at the end of the script will finally print the input line.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***only*** for fun:

```
join -a2 FILE <(seq -f "%g 0 0 0 0 0" $(tail -1 FILE | cut -d' ' -f1)) | cut -d' ' -f -6
```

produces:

```
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 2 3 4 5
6 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 0 0 0 0
8 1 2 3 4 5
9 1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
awk '{x=$1-b;while(x-->1){print ++b," 0 0 0 0 0"};b=$1}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
5  1 2 3 4 5
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```

```
$ awk '{x=$1-b;while(x-->1){print ++b," 0 0 0 0 0"};b=$1}1' file
1  1 2 3 4 5
2  1 2 3 4 5
3  0 0 0 0 0
4  0 0 0 0 0
5  1 2 3 4 5
6  0 0 0 0 0
7  0 0 0 0 0
8  1 2 3 4 5
9  1 2 3 4 5
10 1 2 3 4 5
11 1 2 3 4 5
```